# set login credentials and to move on to next page and display next page

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm having difficulty with my code to set login credentials and to move on to next page and display next page

**HTML CODE**
i'm using ng-model to get data on js file on login controller

```
<form method="post" >
    <div id="form-wrapper"  ng-controller="LoginCtrl">                     


        <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
         <h2 class="light">
           Enter Username</h2> <input  type="text" id="username" ng-model="username" placeholder="Username">
        </label>

        <label class="item item-input item-floating-label">
         <h2 class="light">    
          Enter Password</h2> <input type="Password" id="password" ng-model="password" placeholder="*********">
        </label>
        <button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="login()">
           login
        </button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

**JS CODE
STATES**

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$stateProvider
.state('home', {
url: '/home',
templateUrl: 'page2.html',
controller: 'HomeCtrl'
})
.state('login', {
url: '/login',
templateUrl: 'lndex.html',
controller: 'LoginCtrl'
})

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
});
```

**HOME PAGE CONTROLLER**

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])
.controller('HomeCtrl', function() {
this.photos = [
'img/weq.gif',
'img/a.gif',
'img/b.gif',
'img/c.gif',
'img/d.gif',
'img/qw.gif',
];
});
```

**LOGIN PAGE CONTROLLER**

This is the main file as it's controlling my ionic module, the problem is when I click on login button on html page then nothing happened.kindly if anyone can help me with this problem?

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])
.controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, LoginService, $ionicPopup, $state) {

$scope.data = {

};

$scope.login = function() {
console.log("LOGIN user: " + $scope.username + " - PW: " + $scope.password);

LoginService.loginUser($scope.username, $scope.password).success(function(data) {
  console.log("Login Successful");
    $state.go('home');
}).error(function(data) {
    var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
        title: 'Login failed!',
         template: 'Please check your credentials!'
   });
 });
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided everything else is correct, remove `method="post"` from your form html make it similar to following:

```
<form novalidate ng-submit="login()">

// your input boxes
....

  <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Comment: a minor comment before i think of sth else ... your templateUrl is Lndex.html ... probably is index.html .. also, see any error on console ?

Comment: yes i already removed that bug but its still not going anywhere